# Kubernetes: access "public" urls from within a pod

Tags: dns, kubernetes

First of all, I am not very expert of K8s, I understand some of the concepts and made already my hands dirty in the configurations.

I correctly set up the cluster configured by my company but I have this issue

I am working on a cluster with 2 pods, ingress rules are correctly configured for `www.my-app.com` and `dashboard.my-app.com`. 
Both pods runs on the same VM.

If I enter in the `dashboard` pod (`kubectl exec -it $POD bash`) and try to `curl http://www.my-app.com` I land on the `dashboard` pod again (the same happens all the way around, from `www` to `dashboard`).
I have to use `http://www-svc.default.svc.cluster.local` and `http://dashboard-svc.default.svc.cluster.local` to land on the correct pods but this is a problem (links generated by the other app will contain internal k8s host, instead of the "public url").

Is there a way to configure routing so I can access pods with their "public" hostnames, from the pods themselves?

Answer (score 0):

So what should happen when you curl is the external DNS record (www.my-app.com in this case) will resolve to your external IP address, usually a load balancer that then sends traffic to a kubernetes service.  That service then should send traffic to the appropriate pod.  It would seem that you have a misconfigured service. Make sure your service has an external IP that is different between dashboard and www.  To see this a simple `kubectl get svc` should suffice.  My guess is that the external IP is wrong, or the service is pointing to the wrong podm which you can see with a `kubectl describe svc <name of service>`.

Comment: This is an useful point of view. Actually both services run on the same external IP, is there any solution with this scenario?

Comment: separate ports then? I don't think Kubernetes would allow port-sharing.